# com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: Failed to get document because the client is offline. Android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I get this run time error that I do not understand the reason behind it.

`com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: Failed to get document because the client is offline.`

Below is the code in my Activity that tries to fetch data from the cloud Firestore

```
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("room-id-1").document("participan-name-1");
    docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                if (document != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: " + task.getResult().getData());
                    userData.registerUserToHotspot(roomId_str, participantName_str);
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
            }
        }
    });
```

Is there something I can do about this?

Comment: I am in the same problem. the FirebaseFirestoreException.Code is "UNAVAILABLE". And it means that "The service is currently unavailable. This is a most likely a transient condition and may be corrected by retrying with a backoff." I don't know what should I do now...

Comment: I saw that this error is cause when you have no connection or the client is unavailable, perharps, I'm having a problem with it becasue Im getting this error with a Force Close even when I'm, managing the exception in the same way yo do. And Which is more funny, the error is happening always with the first query after recover my internet. Example: `Flight mode > Do nothing > off Flight mode > wait 20s > query something > Failed to get document because the client is offline.`

This is an error from the API? It's just happening in Android, not in IOS

Comment: Any progress on this, this is an absolute deal breaker.  Not able to use Firestore with Android?

Comment: Hi! Is there any news on this? I'm still facing the exact same issue today on firebase-firestore:17.1.1.

Comment: I am getting this error only in the case of running emulators. If I remove the Firestore emulator's code, everything just works fine.

Answer (score 4):

This happens because `OnCompleteListener` is triggered when the task is completed, either it fails or succeeds. To avoid the error, you can use separate `OnSuccessListener` and `OnFailureListener`.

`OnSuccessListener` is called when the task is succeeded, but if the above error occurs, `OnFailureListener` will be triggered and you can handle the error in `onFailure()` method of the listener.

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 3):

If nothing helped and you sure that all good to go, do next steps:

1. Clean project (Build -> Clean Project). You can also "Invalidate and Caches" with "Clean project" for more safety.
2. Delete **google-services.json** from your project and sync.
3. Build project. Android studio will throw build exception about missing **google-services.json**, It's okey.
4. Download again **google-services.json** from Firebase console, put it in project and sync.
5. Build and run.

Hoping I'm helped to some one

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exception when I used wrong path to the document. When I fixed the path it started to work.

Anyway, the error message is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the solution was to create a new emulator in Android Studio and run the app there

Answer (score 0):

if you are using rxjava then it wiil be simple to catch throwable this way:

```
RxFirestore.getDocument(FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    .collection("info")
    .document("app"))
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribe(snapshot -> {

    }, throwable -> Timber.e(throwable))
```

Otherwise try somehow catch it in promise or/and try-catch block

Answer (score 0):

For me, I faced this issue because i forgot to initialize my firestore database from the Firebase console. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I faced with this problem on emulators below API 19 and asked Firebase support team.
They responded to me that is a secure connection problem and they suggested to me enabling TLS on that emulators.
As far as I understand, Firebase requires up-to-date security provider for connections.
If you think all of your Firebase configurations are correct and still facing with this problem on emulators below API 19, be sure emulator has up-to-date security provider.

Please check "TLS on Android" section at this link: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/SECURITY.md#tls-on-android

Google says it provides a up-to-date provider via Google Play Services. If you want to use that, there is a document.

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-gms-provider.html

Answer (score 0):

Before doing any of the deletions or other suggested things, just try these two:

- Restart your mobile device on which you're testing.
- Connect to a different internet connection and try.

For me, my device was connected to a public Wifi but the internet was not working even though it was working fine just some moments ago. My scenario was that I deleted and installed the app again on my Android device and after that, I started getting the same error. So doing the above two worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I use Windows 11. What worked for me was:

1. Go to `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`.
2. Rename `emulator` folder to `emulator_original`.
3. Create a new device from device manager. In the process, it will ask you to install emulator.
4. Install the emulator.
5. Start the device.