# Firestore fails to retrieve data after reconnecting to the Internet

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firestore with the Android SDK (11.6.2) and I'm hitting an exception when my device was offline and reconnects to the Internet.

When requesting a document, firestore fails with the following task exception :

> com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: Failed to get document because the client is offline.

However, the device is connected, I can make network requests beside using Firestore and they succeed.
This error is not consistent, sometimes the request will succeed right after reconnecting to the Internet. Sometimes, the request fails again and again, then succeeds, sometimes more than one minute after the device has been reconnected to the Internet.

Here is a sample request that produces the exception:

```
val docRef = firestore.collection("foo").document("bar")
docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
    if (task.isSuccessful) {
        Log.d("FirestoreSourceSet", "Get document success")
    } else {
        Log.e("FirestoreSourceSet", "Get document error", task.exception)
    }
}
```

I'm not using the offline capabilities of Firestore, thus the FirebaseFirestore instance is initialized the first time with the `setPersistenceEnabled(false)` flag:

```
val firestoreSettings = FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
    .setPersistenceEnabled(false)
    .build()

val firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().apply {
    this.firestoreSettings = firestoreSettings
}
```

Why is Firestore returning this error even though the device is online? Am I missing something in the Firestore configuration that would avoid this error?

I tried upgrading Firebase to the 11.8.0 version, but I encounter the same behavior.

### Logs

These are the logs while trying to fetch sync some data with Firestore (which begins with a document fetch) after leaving airplane mode: https://pastebin.com/xDMG2Pzj

The network is already available before the first Firestore call, as I waited for the Wifi to settle, and check it using the [ConnectivityManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html) of Android before proceeding with Firestore.

The multiple calls are because I manually retry using a button each time I get the error until the document is successfully retrieved.

The first line of the log is when I turn the airplane mode one, which closes the stream of Firestore.

### Edit: Issue

Firebase doesn't have a public tracker, but I reported the issue using [their report tool](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/), and [made a repo that reproduces the issue](https://github.com/AoDevBlue/FirestoreClientIsOfflineIssue).

They acknowledged the issue but could not provide an ETA, so we have to wait:

> If we release the fix, we will announce it in our release notes page.

This is still an issue as of firestore-core 17.0.4

Comment: Is there a significant delay between when you call `get()` and when the error message is output? In my experience Firestore tries to connect for about 30 seconds, so knowing the delay helps to determine what phase it is in. I'd also recommend [enabling debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestore.html#setLoggingEnabled(boolean)) to see if the traffic on the wire gives a hint as to why the client can't connect.

Comment: Most of the time, the delay is 4 to 5 seconds between the call and the error. Sometimes, it's less than a second, sometimes it takes up to 10s. I enabled the logging and updated my post with it.

Comment: I have this problem too on Android, even though i use offline persistence. Any progress on this?

Comment: The same issue. Any news from their side?

Comment: Facing same issue. Any updates?

Comment: Sadly, I have no update on this. The fix will be announced in the release notes when available, but we have no ETA. The issue is still present using firestore-core 17.0.4

Comment: Still experiencing this with Firestore 17.1.5.

Comment: And with 19.0.0.

Comment: Experiencing the same issue March 2020... Any updates?

Comment: Same issue in December 2020

Comment: And again today with 22.0.1. I can't continue development with this show-stopper. Is anyone listening??

Comment: Still happening with Firestore 22.1.2. This is very frustrating :(

Comment: Still happening with Firestore 23.0.0. very disappointing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was fixed by the release 17.1.5 of Cloud Firestore.

See the official changelog https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android

> Cloud Firestore now recovers more quickly from bad network states.

---

Using my reproduction project with the version 18.0.0, the issue is indeed not present.

Comment: Version 20.1.0 and it's the very same behaviour as described in the question. I don,t think it's fixed at all.

Comment: I'm using the firestore sdk 19.0.0 for android and I'm still have this problem when i was try to get a document by id, which doesn't exist

Comment: And I'm still experiencing the problem with 21.7.1

Comment: @gbixahue Exact same problem for me. It works, unless I'm trying to retrieve a document by id that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 5):

From the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline):

> To use offline persistence, you don't need to make any changes to the code that you use to access Cloud Firestore data. With offline persistence enabled, the Cloud Firestore client library automatically manages online and offline data access and synchronizes local data when the device is back online.

When you initialize Cloud Firestore, you can enable or disable offline persistence. So, when using the following line of code:

```
val firestoreSettings = FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
    .setPersistenceEnabled(false)
    .build()
```

You actually set the persistence to `false`, you are disabling this feature. To solve this, just remove this line of code. Firestore has `.setPersistenceEnabled(true)` by default.

Comment: I don't want to use the persistence of Firestore, as I'm already using a local database to store data, thus the explicit disable.

I'm fine with getting an error when the device is offline if I attempt to retrieve data from Firestore. My problem is getting this `Failed to get document because the client is offline` error when the device is online, after reconnecting to the Internet.

Comment: Why to use another database to store data when Cloud Firestore provides the same thing while doing nothing? You don't even need to specify this, Firestore has .setPersistenceEnabled(true) by default. So, as i read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46620957/com-google-firebase-firestore-firebasefirestoreexception-failed-to-get-document) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46602889/firebase-cloud-firestore-throws-client-is-offline), it might be an issue that will be solved soon. Remember, Cloud Firestore is still in beta version.

Comment: Thank you for pointing to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46620957/com-google-firebase-firestore-firebasefirestoreexception-failed-to-get-document), I did not find it but it's the same problem. I understand that Cloud Firestore is still in beta, but I wanted to know if it was something on our end.
I found this [page](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) to report issues, but can't find an issue tracker so that I can track this issue if already known.

Comment: Have you tried to [enabling debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestore#setLoggingEnabled(boolean))? Have you seen something weird?

Comment: I enabled debug logging and updated my post to include to it. Firestore fails to resolve host "firestore.googleapis.com" repeatedly while increasing the backoff until it manages to establish a connection.

Comment: I recomend you post another question and add all those logs and maybe one of the Firebase team members will answer it. Or send this issue to Firebase Support. Keep me also posted.

Comment: In fact, the problem still has not been resolved. It appears in Firestore 22.0.1.

Answer (score 2):

I'm facing the same issue since 2018 and have not yet found a proper solution. It is still happening with version 22.1.2 of the Firestore library for Android. As commented in the [source code](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/2b7f90b5bed3f05b991207715534b2fed45d7d49/firebase-firestore/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference.java#L322-L334) of `DocumentReference`, this exception is thrown when the client is offline and the requested document is not available in the local cache. There is also a recent [explanation](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/2575#issuecomment-817923593) of this behaviour by Denver Coneybeare.

This exception might occur for `DocumentReference.get()` calls. Here's an exemplary stack trace:

```
com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: Failed to get document because the client is offline.
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.lambda$getViaSnapshotListener$1(DocumentReference.java:331)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference$$Lambda$2.onEvent(DocumentReference.java:8)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.lambda$addSnapshotListenerInternal$2(DocumentReference.java:504)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference$$Lambda$3.onEvent(DocumentReference.java:16)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.AsyncEventListener.lambda$onEvent$0(AsyncEventListener.java:42)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.AsyncEventListener$$Lambda$1.run(AsyncEventListener.java:2)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.Executors$$Lambda$1.execute(Executors.java)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.AsyncEventListener.onEvent(AsyncEventListener.java:39)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.QueryListener.raiseInitialEvent(QueryListener.java:176)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.QueryListener.onViewSnapshot(QueryListener.java:95)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.EventManager.addQueryListener(EventManager.java:97)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.FirestoreClient.lambda$listen$6(FirestoreClient.java:160)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.FirestoreClient$$Lambda$6.run(FirestoreClient.java:12)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue.lambda$enqueue$2(AsyncQueue.java:436)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$$Lambda$2.call(AsyncQueue.java:1)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor.lambda$executeAndReportResult$1(AsyncQueue.java:322)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$$Lambda$2.run(AsyncQueue.java:1)
       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$DelayedStartFactory.run(AsyncQueue.java:229)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

I'm sorry if this answer does not solve the problem, but this information would have been too long for a comment on the original post.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem. There is workaround - application waits some time and makes another attempt to get the data from server.

Here is mockup  (this is Flutter/dart):

```
   List<Course> items;

   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
    loadData();
    ...
    //building th UI with data from items list
    ...
   }


    loadData() async {        
        //is not loaded but there is internet connection
        if (!isLoaded&&isConnected) {
          try {
              querySnapshot = await query.getDocuments(source: Source.server);
            } 
            catch (ex) {
              print(ex);
              Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 10), () {
              // setState to trigger build 10 seconds later to make one more attempt
                  setState(() {
                      isLoaded = false;
                  });
              });
          return;
        }
    // here goes the code to handle the result 
    items =  querySnapshot.documents.map((s) => Course.fromDb(s)).toList();
    }
```

Comment: This is your first answer, so I don't want to discourage you from providing answers in the future by down voting it, but you are offering a very generic time-based re-try workaround, as a fix for a bug in a specific framework,not to mention you wrote it in a different language, so even if the user found the general idea to be helpful, it could still be in a language she/he doesnt really understand and so on)
Try to think of the needed use-cases, setting a sleep/timeout or any other kind of a process delay is never the best solution, so it's even worst when suggested as a general workaround

Comment: On top of all that, this answer was updated a couple of times, the way you wrote your answer suggests that you didn't really read the full question, is the user already states that it's a bug, the framework devs are informed and working on a fix, so your contribution is mainly confusing, and not very helpful.

Comment: Hi Samer Murad, ok, I see your point. Yes, I know that the developer of the framework is working on the fix, and ofcourse the time-based re-try fixes are not the best solution. But on the other hand: 1. I didn't see any other suggested solutions for the problem (if you know any - could you provide link please? It would be much appreciated) 2. The framework developer  is not fixed the issue yet, but the bugs in applications must be fixed

Answer (score 0):

this may help

Java:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

//to reconnect
db.terminate();
db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
```

Kotlin:

```
var db = Firebase.firestore

//to reconnect
db.terminate()
db = Firebase.firestore
```